# symbol.cab missing digital signature

Tags: packages, miktex

I am trying to run an Elsevier template, and apparently it needs the file symbol.cab. Miktex (2.9) tries to download this automatically from http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ but gets the error "Error response from server: 403."

Now, I've read the threads about using the package manager and I tried that. The download fails. I even went to the address in my browser to download manually. Turns out, my work network is blocking the download because it is missing a digital signature.

Is there anywhere else I can download this (and possible other) files where they might have a digital signature? Or will I have to download this from another computer and email it to myself or carry it in on a flash drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the package `repository`:

[image]

I suppose not all of them are missing a digital signature. A British, French or German repository should be OK.

As a last resort, you could try downloading by hand from one of the three canonical sites with Filezilla. Packages are located in:

…/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages

E.g., for `Dante` goto `ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`.

You should download, not only symbol.cab, but also these 4 files:

- pr.ini
- miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
- miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma
- files.csv.lzma
  Then change package repository to a `local` one  — the directory where you store these files.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I had no trouble downloading any files from the Dante repository. Thanks!